# can we use single node configuration after i configure multi node?I am talking about hadoop

Tags: linux, hadoop, bigdata

this question might be a silly one but since i am new in hadoop and there are very few material available online which can be used as  a reference point so i thought this might be the best place to ask this question .

i have successfully configured few computers in multi node configuration. during the setup process i have to change many hadoop file .now i am wondering  can i use every single  computer as an single node configuration with out changing  any settings or hadoop file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your each node as separate instance. But you have to modify the configuration files surely and restart all the instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that

Follow below steps

1. Remove IP or Hostname from masters file
2. Remove IP's or hostname's from slaves file
3. change fs.defaultFS property IP address in core-site.xml
4. As well as Resource Manager IP